# Should be really simple, how do I make a jbutton show a jframe i have already created via the window builder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

Not sure if I'm just using a visual basic approach, but I was under the impression i could use the window builder in eclipse to create my Jframes, then simply invoke them when the button/actionlistener is selected...

Like:

```
JButton btn_register = new JButton("Register");
        btn_register.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frm_register.setvisible(true);

            }
```

frm_register is the class name for the register form...

Comment: What's the problem when you tried this? Are there compiler errors? Runtime errors?

Comment: You need to create a frm_register first: `frm_register myFrame = new frm_register`

Comment: I just had no idea how to approach this, Thanks Nicola, that worked a treat.

Comment: @ReeceMathieson, if the problem has been solved then don't forget to "accept" an answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourFrame frame=new YourFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

> frm_register is the class name for the register form...

I hope not. Class names should start with upper case character. For example: RegistrationForm.

Then you need code like:

```
RegistrationForm  register = new RegistrationForm();
register.setVisible( true );
```

This of course assumes that the constructor for the RegistrationForm adds components to the form and does a pack on the form.

> i could use the window builder in eclipse to create my Jframes,

Also, you should not be using a JFrame. An application generally has a single JFrame. A child window would typically be a JDialog. See: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)